# google ajax api limit the result to 64

Tags: php, google-api

i am using google ajax api with my php script but it is not working above 64 results is there any hack to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to increase the data returned by google. You only get what they're willing to give.

Comment: i find something on this blog comment but dont know how to do this http://www.teamlalala.com/blog/2009/01/05/google-api-limits-results-to-64-which-limits-the-types-of-businesses-you-can-build/